# Checking which function modifies the variable in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I am having a problem with a project in android studio.

I don't know which function is changing my variable value and I want to see what's responsible for changing it. 
Is there any way to see which function/constructor does modify the variable ?

I have already added the variable to the Watches, but that only shows when the value changes. So is there any way to see the function that does change it specifically after it has another value ?

Comment: You might be able to right click on variable > Find Usages

Comment: as @cricket_007 said, then add breakpoint for each one, and debug the app

Comment: @cricket_007  know the function which is supposed to change it, and I know where the variable is declared. The variable is only changed by one function, that one function is not called and the variable does change.

Comment: @Yazan already done that, breakpoint shows that the function is not executed while debugging but still the variable is assigned. Only one function assigns the variable ....

Comment: anyway the point of this question is if there is any way to check this, I will post another more detailed question on what's happening in more detail.

Comment: is this variable `private`? if no you may have accessed it directly and modified it's value some where in the code. also, sometimes i set (hardcoded) values for testing, some variables, maybe you have done this and forget about it ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking then. Find Usages will show you the lines of code that declare and modify that variable

Comment: @Yazan yes the variable is private, the code which I am working right now is not mine. Only one function does change the variable and that function is not called, pretty sure about this since I put breakpoints all over. FindUsages confirmed this... I don't know what I am missing, but I will post a more detailed question regarding this one in some minutes. Since this is a general question and you will not get any information regarding the problem without code. I will give you a link after i do in here :)

Comment: @cricket_007 the question above is clear, I want  to see what function changes the variable in runtime. Only one function changes the variable and that function is not called, confirmed via findusages and while debugging it with breakpoints. I can see the value change, I want to see what changes it.

Comment: @cricket_007 I will tag you too when I do post the more detailed question, since you clearly have ideas on it :)

Comment: You can just edit this question, there is no reason to post another that I can tell

Comment: @cricket_007 this one had a specific meaning and a question. The other one will be a different question although it is related with it all along, so I would prefer posting a new one